# How to modify default Exif metadata output in R

Tags: r, exif

When I save a plot in R the image file gets littered with useless Exif metadata:

```
...
Profile File Signature          : acsp
...
Device Manufacturer             : appl
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
...
Profile Creator                 : app
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Description             : Generic RGB Profile
...
Profile Copyright               : Copyright 2007 Apple Inc., all rights reserved.
...
```

Where does it come from? Can I modify the Exif metadata that is generated globally or every time I plot an image?

Here is an example:

```
png("test.png")
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
dev.off()
```

I am using:

- R 3.4.0
- macOS El Capitan 10.11

Comment: That's not EXIF, it's [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) info. Generic RGB Profile is what apple assigns when no other has been specified. You can remove or change it, but that could mess up how it's displayed.

Comment: @AkselA All those attributes do not appear when I create the image on a Linux machine. And some of them are clearly not needed (like the copyright field)

Comment: Sure, but what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To clear the EXIF metadata, you can [install imagemagick](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/) on your system and then invoke it from R via system call:

```
png("test.png")
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
dev.off()

# Strip metadata with an imagemagick command: convert input_file -strip output_file  
system("convert test.png -strip test.png")
```

Ideally, you would use the [magick package from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/), but AFAIK it doesn't support the strip function, so I guess a system call is the next best thing.

Comment: I am doing something very similar right now (using [`exiftool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool)) but there hast to be a way of doing it natively. The tags are not generated in the Linux distribution.